# Django users and permissions

Tags: django

I need to develop a scenario of users and groups in my django application there are three groups 
   - Admin
   - Manager
   - Employee
Generally admin is available by creating superuser and I need to create the users for different groups
 - Admin can access all the records created by all users

Now my requirement is some users are belongs manager group and some normal users belongs to employee group..

- How the associate user belongs to manager group can fetch his own records along with his subordinate user's records from employee group

I'm fully confused to give relation between normal users with an associate user from manager group.

How can I assign some employee users to a manager user?

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure we are on the same page, you wish to have the following user structure:

- An **Admin** can see EVERYTHING
- A **Manager** can see HIMSELF and all his associated **Users**
- A **User** can see HIMSELF and that's it

So technically, there's only a relation between **Managers and Users**

Assuming your **Admin** is not the same as the native admin role from Django, you could setup the following logic:

- Extend the User model with a 1-to-1 relation to your custom model. Let's call it `Profile`.
- One of the field in `Profile` could be the `role` which would either be Admin, Manager, or User (might want to create a referantial table and use a foreign key)
- Another field could be `related_manager` which would be a foreign key to the user model. It would be a way to say *"that user is my manager"*

You would need to add specific control in your model, notably:

- `related_manager` is required (or optional?) if user is "User".
- `related_manager` is forced to `None` if user is not "User"
- `related_manager` must be a user with 'Manager' role
- You'd probably have to setup `signals` to handle "What happens when a Manager, who had users to manage, becomes a basic User?" Do these users become manager-less? Or maybe you prevent it from happening, and a manager can only be demoted once he has no user attached? It all depends on what you want

Note that this is **one of many** ways to deal with your situation